# Red boxes around navigation buttons in Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

When I am trying to create a presentation in Beamer, all of the navigation buttons have red boxes around them and I can't seem to find anything in the code which would cause this.  When I hide the navigation symbols, the boxes go away as well but there is also a red box around the title in the footer of each slide.  Has anyone seen this before and know how to fix it?  The odd thing is that this is now happening when I compile presentations that I made awhile ago which have never given me any trouble, but now when I run them they have the navigation button and footer boxes.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code for my presentation (currently of only the title page):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title[Title]{Presentation Title}

\author[Name]{Name}

\date{Date}

\begin{document} 

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

and here is what I am getting from this:
[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Did you change any hyperref settings? How do you compile your document? Pdflatex or something else?

Comment: I am using TexWorks, I did make any hyperref setting changes, and I believe (correct me if I am wrong) that this demonstrates a MWE:  \documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\title[Title]{Presentation Title}

\author[Name]{Name}

\date{Date}

\begin{document} 

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}

Comment: (Sorry about the formatting there, I could not find a way to spread it out as it is displayed in the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please add the .log file of your MWE? If it is too long to add to the question, you could post it to pastebin.com

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  And I am currently trying to find the .log file, but I will post it once I do so.

Comment: The `.log` file is probably in the same folder as your `.tex` and has the same name

Comment: I believe I found the .log file.  It is at https://pastebin.com/9BqCaXb9.

Comment: The problem is the option clash for the hyperref package in l. 17 of your file. Is this really exactly the same file as you show in your question? The line numbers don't seem to match

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the error message seems to originate from parts of the code not shown in the question